# Find the value of $a$ so the function $x^3-ax$ is increasing on $]-\infty, \infty[$

Tags: calculus

> Find the value of $a$ so the function $x^3-ax$ is increasing on $]-\infty, \infty[$?

So the derivative in $3x^2-a$. In order that the function always increases then $b^2-4ac \leq 0$ right? Which means $a \leq 0$, but the answer in my textbook is $a = 0$.

Comment: You should really try to find a better title for your question. (Also, 'quadratic-forms' is not a suitable tag.)

Comment: Took the liberty of editing title and tag.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the function is increasing for every choice of $a \le 0$.